# How do I get this align?

Tags: node.js, json, text, discord.js

I have been working on something and I want to be able to align this so it looks neat to the user and doesn't look stupid. Here is my current code I have been using to attempt to line it up however it doesn't work.

This is an image of what it looks like

[image]

due to my rep I cannot post images directly.

```js
let serverArray = [];
for (let serverName of serverNamesUS) {
  if (serverName.status < 0.75) {
    serverName.format = "\t\t\tNormal";
  } else if (serverName.status == 0.75) {
    serverName.format = "\t\t\tCrowded";
  } else if (serverName.status == 1.00) {
    serverName.format = "\t\t\tFull";
  }
  serverArray.push(serverName.name + ":\t" + serverName.format + '\n');
}

console.log(serverArray);

let serverStatus = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor("Current Server Statistics", client.user.displayAvatarURL)
  .setColor(0xeeffee)
  .addField("United States Server Respone", `\`\`\`ini\n${serverArray.toString().replace(/,/g, "")}\`\`\``)
  .addField("Europe Server Respone", "a")
  .addField("Asia Server Respone", "a");

msg.channel.send(serverStatus);
```

Comment: Interesting, perhaps try on the sandbox?

Comment: https://github.com/timoxley/columnify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.addField` with inline flag.

```
.addField("United States Server", "USEast\nUSEast2\nUSEast3", true)
.addField("Respone", "Normal\nCrowded\nNormal", true);
```

I also recommend these visualizers to check:

- https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/
- https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/